# Controller not firing on .jsp page hit MVC Spring JAVA

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

Trying to get a Spring MVC controller to fire when a .jsp page in my web project is hit directly.

Web XML for the dispatcher servlet:

```
    <servlet>
<servlet-name>MYAPP</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>MYAPP</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In the dispatcher configuration I have the following bean defined:

```
<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Controller Class:

```
 package com.mydomain.controllers;

 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
 import com.mydomain.security.Authorization;

 @Controller
 public class CustomerController {


@RequestMapping("/customer")
public String customer(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (Authorization.SessionCheck(request))
        return "../customer/customer";
    else
        return "redirect:http://elsewhere.com"; 

}

  }
```

Off the root, I have a jsp page in /WebContent/customer/customer.jsp
If, in a browser, I hit http://myhost.com/MYAPP/customer, the controller processes the customer method above just fine.  However, if I hit http://myhost.com/MYAPP/customer/customer.jsp, then the controller never fires and just the customer.jsp page is rendered.   How do I get the controller to process when the .jsp page is hit?

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your JSPs in WEB-INF directory - this will prevent users from accessing jsps directly. Then without step 2 the users will get 404/
2. You could update your Controller mapping to something like  `@RequestMapping("/customer*")`  - but be very very careful with it

Answer (score 0):

> However, if I hit http://myhost.com/MYAPP/customer/customer.jsp, then
>   the controller never fires

Why do you expect it to? Your `@Controller`'s handler method is mapped to

```
@RequestMapping("/customer")
```

so that is the path it will handle. If you want it to handle other paths, add another path or more handler methods.

As to why the JSP is rendered, that's because it is in the `WebContent` folder of your web application. Any file there is accessible directly.